# Dynamic notification to other user (actionscript 3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, actionscript

I need some of your help.

User **A** and user **B** have same loaded swf file.
What I want: For example, user **A** clicks button, and user **B** see notification "User A clicked button" dynamically.

Help me please.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash doesn't handle this kind of scenario out of the box. You'll have to implement some server backend using PHP or Perl for example.

Then have the SWF A sends a request to the server when user A clicks a button, and save the message "User A clicked button" (or anything else you want). Then SWF B can check every X seconds if some message is available. If it is, display it.